# Как правильно написать @media с оператором not?

Tags: css, media-queries

Как написать медиа-запрос чтобы были все устройства при альбомной ориентации, но с размером меньшим чем указанное? То есть в коде примерно что-то такое должно быть -

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) and (not min-width: 300px) and (not min-height: 500px){}
```

То есть мне нужно производить с кодом действие только тогда, когда альбомная ориентация, но при условии что размер вьюпорта меньше 300х500.

Comment: `not min-width: 500px = max-width: 500px`

Comment: @MasterAlex не совсем понимаю о чем Вы...Я прошу помочь мне составить медиа запрос, который срабатывает при альбомной ориентации при экране меньше чем 500х500. При это 1000х300 должна проходить.

Comment: @MasterAlex, неверно. Значение 500 не попадает в первое, но попадает во второй.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Альбомная ориентация с высотой более 500 и шириной менее 500 вызывает сомнения.

Вероятно, надо так:

```
@media all and (max-height: 500px)
```

Comment: размеры я из головы взял, то есть придумал.

Comment: @IvanPetrov, надо задавать вопрос точнее. И попробуй скобки добавить, я не уверен, нужны они там или нет.

Comment: исправил вопрос и добавил ПОЗАБЫТОЕ второе not

Comment: @IvanPetrov 1. Попробуй тут добавить скобки: `(not min-width: 300px)` => `(not (min-width: 300px))`. 2. Почему бы вместо `not min-*` не использовать `max-*`? 3. В `landscape` высота ведь не может быть больше ширины?